# Переписать код используя оператор switch

Tags: c++

В зависимости от стажа работы на предприятии внедрена надбавка к окладу
размере для работников

от 5 до 10 лет – 10%;

от 10 от 15 лет – 15%;

свыше 15 лет – 20%.

Составить программу, которая по заданному стажу работы определить размер надбавки в
процентах.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int a;
        cout << "Напишите свой опыт работы: ";
        cin >> a;
        bool p = (a >= 5 && a <= 10);
        cout << p;
        switch (a >= 5 && a <= 10)
        {
        case true:
            cout << "Надбавка 10%" << endl;
            break;}
    
        switch (a > 10 && a <= 15) {
        case true:
            cout << "Надбавка 15%";
            break;}
    
        switch (a > 15) {
        case true:
            cout << "Надбавка 20%";
            break;}
    }
```

Препод говорит, что код написан неправильно, хотя в компиляторе все выводится правильно.

Comment: Препод явно хочет `case 0: case1: case2: case3: case4: .... break; case 5: case 6: case7:` — ну, вы поняли...

Comment: @Harry Препод не настолько дуб, и наверняка хочет, чтобы студент поделил стаж на 5.

Comment: @gbg Ох, сомневаюсь...

Comment: @Harry а что тогда делать, если " а > 15 "  ?

Comment: А это `default:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Напишите свой опыт работы: ";
    cin >> age;

    switch ((int)((age < 0 ? 0 : age) / 5))
    {
        case 0:
            break;
            
        case 1:
            cout << "Надбавка 10%" << endl;
            break;
        
        case 2:
            cout << "Надбавка 15%";
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Надбавка 20%";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а при вводе отрицательного числа?

Comment: не подразумевал, но можно так `(int)((age < 0 ? 0 : age) / 5)`